# How to verify solutions for Logic functions having ampersand symbol (used in Logic package)

Tags: logic, maple

For example, if we have a logic function *F = (x1 or x2) and (not x2)* then we can verify a solution [x1=true, x2=false] of equation F = true this way:

```
[> F:=(x1 or x2) and (not x2):
   subs({x1=true,x2=false},F);
                                     true
```

Maple **Logic** package has a nice function **Satisfy**, which can find a solution, but function F (now it's named as G) has to be written using symbol & (before *and*, *or*, *not*):

```
[> G:=(x1 &or x2) &and (&not x2):
   A:=Logic[Satisfy](G);
                           A := {x1 = true, x2 = false}
```

But I don't know an easy way how to verify a solution (I mean not in this specific case, but in general, functions may have hundreds of variables). My attempt was to use substitution and then use **evalb**, but it didn't work:

```
[> G1:=subs(A,G);
   evalb(G1);
                   G1:= (true &or false) &and &not(false)
                      (true &or false) &and &not(false)
```

But for function F the substitution worked (even without evalb):

```
[> F1:=subs(A,F);
                                F1:=true
```

Also I couldn't find an easy way to remove ampersand symbol & from an expression (in order to construct function F from function G).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
G := (x1 &or x2) &and (&not x2):

cand := {x1=true, x2=false}:
```

Given the logical expression assigned to `G` in form of used by the `Logic` package (ie. operators with names prefixed by `&`), then the candidate solution assigned to `cand` can be tested as follows:

```
BG := Logic:-Export(G, form=boolean);

      BG := (x1 or x2) and not x2

eval(BG, cand);

               true
```

Combining those two steps,

```
eval(Logic:-Export(G, form=boolean), cand);

               true
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution similar to @acer's, but the opposite direction. If you are not using anything else other than `Satisfy` from the `Logic` package and you are fine with having your logical formulas as in `F` in your example, then there is no need to have your formula saved in the `Logic`'s style with ampersand operations. Instead of `Export` in @acer's answer, use `Import`. Here is how it works in your example.

```
F := (x1 or x2) and (not x2):
A := Logic:-Satisfy( Logic:-Import( F ) );
F1 := subs( A, F );
```

Note that `Package:-Command` is the same as `Packae[Command]` with tiny differences. You can also use `eval( F, A )` instead of `subs( A, F )`. For their differences you can check Maple help pages. But here they give the same results as you want.